# How to interact with One Drive using C++

Tags: visual-c++, onedrive

I'm looking for a way to interact with OneDrive through C++. I need to log in and download/upload the file from a known location.

I tried to install curl in VS 2019/2017 using vcpkg but could not, it does not inclide to the code.

Comment: I installed curl. If you know useful guide about curl please write to comment

Comment: It is done with [OneDrive REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online)  (I used it in C++ in a Freeware to access thousands of images on OneDrive)

Comment: I know this API, but I want to implement http requests myself.

Comment: That's what I did, with WinHTTP + REST commands

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your last message

Comment: I send GET requests with WinHTTP by using the REST syntax, for example like in the samples from        
         [Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: How you log in?

Comment: With tokens at login.live.com, but it is complicated... ([OneDrive authentication and sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)